# @ModelAttribute at method level

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am referring the example from [here](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-using-modelattribute-in.html)

where the @ModelAttribute is placed at the method level

```
 /**
  * Retrieves all addresses and allows them to be used as a model
  * @return a model attribute containing addresses
  */
 @ModelAttribute("addresses")
 public List<Address> getAllAddresses() {
  // Delegate to service
  return addressService.getAll();
 }



@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new             CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}

 /**
  * Handles and retrieves a JSP page containing all addresses.
  * We use the @ModelAttribute to pass the data to the view
  * 
  * @return the name of the JSP page
  */
    @RequestMapping(value="list1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllUsingModelAttribute() {
     logger.debug("Received request to show all addresses page");

     // No need to add the model here
     // It has been automatically added when we used the @ModelAttribute annotation earlier
     // The name of the ModelAttribute is "addresses". Your JSP should reference "addresses"

     // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addressespage.jsp
     return "addressespage";
 }
```

My question is, is the method annotated with @ModelAttribute autofired when the request comes to the controller? In this case method getAllAddresses(). As in the example I don't see this method called explicitly anywhere.

Or it is fired when the request comes to the method immediately placed after it containing @RequestMapping?

Same question for @initBinder is the method annotated with it autofired after form submission?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug your controller and put some logging statements.

The first things you culd see is the call to `@ModelAttribute` annotated method.

Your `initBinder` will be called if you put a custom object into Model or if your handler method declare a custom Object as parameter.

```
@ModelAttribute("obj")
 public List<Address> getAllAddresses() {
  // Delegate to service
  return new CustomObject();
 }

@RequestMapping(value="list1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllUsingModelAttribute(CustomObject customObject) {
```

Answer (score 3):

When a page is going to render if the page has a form which has been made by form taglib using Spring like:

```
<form:form commandName="addresses" method="post">
```

this lead your page to look for a proper @ModelAndAttribute with name 'addresses'. If your program was able to find that (like the one you have defined)

```
@ModelAttribute("addresses")
public List<Address> getAllAddresses() {
   // Delegate to service
   return addressService.getAll();
}
```

that make a model available for your form with a List ready to change !

then you can use another method for submitting the form like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="path", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSomethingForMe(@Valid @ModelAttribute("addresses") List <Address>, BindingResult result) {
     if(result.hasErrors()){
         return "TO_THE_PAGE_YOU_WANT_FOR_SHOWING_THE_ERROR_TO_USER";
      }

      // do the other stuffs you want !
}
```

I just write this code here, so sorry if you found out any typo problem but that's the story !

Good Luck !